# Words are extending to second column

Tags: two-column

I am newbie to latex and first time writing my thesis in it. I am writing in TWO column format but some words from first column do not fit well and they extend to second column. Picture is attached. In that picture, the word metabolic is extended to second column instead of getting truncated.[image: Image is attached]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It looks like TeX doesn't "know" how to line-break the word "metabolic". If your text uses US-English conventions, try providing the instruction `\hyphenation{met-a-bolic}` in the preamble, and then recompile. By the way, do you use a package such as `babel`? If you do, which language settings are in effect?

Comment: Add also` \usepackage{microtype}` in your preamble.

Comment: you can always test a word to see if it can be hyphenated.  (i find this easiest to do interactively, although it can also be done with a prepared file.)  start up a tex session.  then enter `\relax \showhyphens{metabolic}` followed by a return.  the result will be shown with all "automatic" hyphens.  then end the session (if interactive, then ctrl-c followed by `x` to quit).  @Mico's suggestion is then a good one to follow.

Comment: The other option is the `sloppypar` environment,

Comment: I used pacakage microtype, and problem solved. Thank you all for your kind suggesstions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved by comment